# Perl Hash of Hashes and Counting

Tags: perl, hash, counting

I am trying to process a perl data structure that I have outputted using Data::Dumper

```
$VAR1 = 'GAHD';
$VAR2 = [
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'K. Long',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '7/27/1957',
        'POSITION'      => 'SENIOR OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 57,
        'GRADE'         => 'P5'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'J. Buber',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '12/11/1957',
        'POSITION'      => 'CHIEF',
        'GRADE'         => 'D1'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'M. Amsi',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '1/1/1957',
        'POSITION'      => 'SENIOR ANIMAL HEALTH OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 57,
        'GRADE'         => 'P5'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'E. Xenu',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '8/31/1964',
        'POSITION'      => 'SENIOR OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 50,
        'GRADE'         => 'P5'
    },
];
$VAR3 = 'GAGD';
$VAR4 = [
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'P. Cheru',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '6/18/1966',
        'POSITION'      => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 48,
        'GRADE'         => 'P4'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'B. Burns',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '2/4/1962',
        'POSITION'      => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 52,
        'GRADE'         => 'P4'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'US',
        'NAME'          => 'R. Mung',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '12/13/1968',
        'POSITION'      => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 45,
        'GRADE'         => 'P4'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'GERMANY',
        'NAME'          => 'B. Scherf',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '8/31/1964',
        'POSITION'      => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
        'AGE'           => 50,
        'GRADE'         => 'P4'
    },
    {   'COUNTRY'       => 'GERMANY',
        'NAME'          => 'I. Hoffmann',
        'DATE_OF_BIRTH' => '2/21/1960',
        'POSITION'      => 'CHIEF',
        'AGE'           => 54,
        'GRADE'         => 'P5'
    },
];
```

The following is outputted:

```
1 ADG JUNIOR OFFICER K. King
1 DG SENIOR DIRECTOR K. King
3 P5 SENIOR OFFICER R. Forest
           R.Forest
           K. King
1 P3 JUNIOR OFFICER K. King
3 P1 FORESTRY OFFICER P. Smith
           T. Turner
           K. Turner
1 P1 GENERAL OFFICER K. King
```

I would like to count the number of `GRADES` and `POSITIONS` by Division. Here is the code that I have put together thus far:

```
#Push data read from a flat file and while loop
push @{ $grades{ $_->{GRADE} }{ $_->{POSITION} } }, $_->{NAME} for @$AG;
for my $key (
    sort { substr( $a, 0, 1 ) cmp substr( $b, 0, 1 ) || substr( $b, 0, 2 ) cmp substr( $a, 0, 2 ) }
    keys %grades
    )
{
    for my $pos ( sort { $a cmp $b } keys %{ $grades{$key} } ) {
        my $names = $grades{$key}->{$pos};
        my $count = scalar @$names;

        print $count, ' ', $key, ' ', $pos, ' ', $names->[0], "\n";
        print '        ', $names->[$_], "\n" for 1 .. $#$names;
    }
}
```

The code will stop outputting results if duplicate POSITIONS and GRADES data (i.e. P1, Senior Officer) appear in another Division.

I do not know how to access the Hash of Hash by Division (i.e. GAGD, GAGHD,etc.) so that the same GRADEs and POSITIONs will be outputted per division.

Here is what I really need:

```
**GAGD**
1 ADG JUNIOR OFFICER K. King
1 DG SENIOR DIRECTOR K. King
3 P5 SENIOR OFFICER R. Forest
           R.Forest
           K. King
1 P3 JUNIOR OFFICER K. King
3 P1 FORESTRY OFFICER P. Smith
           T. Turner
           K. Turner
1 P1 GENERAL OFFICER K. King

**GAGHD**
1 P3 JUNIOR OFFICER P. Green
3 P1 FORESTRY OFFICER R. Brown
           F. Boo
           K. Church
1 P1 GENERAL OFFICER D. Peefer

etc.
etc.
```

Comment: It might help to be clear about what your inputs are, what your *expected* output should be and what *actual* output you're getting. This question is close to being clear, but still awful vague.

Comment: Where is the `GAGHD` coming from in your "what you really need" results from? Is that a typo?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1100124

Comment: @PerlGui did the perlmonks solve your problem or are you still pondering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to hash the information by Division, then count and store names by grade + position. The following seems to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %grades = (
    GAHD => [ {
               NAME => 'K. Long',
               POSITION => 'SENIOR OFFICER',
               GRADE => 'P5'
              },
              {
               NAME => 'J. Buber',
               POSITION => 'CHIEF',
               GRADE => 'D1'
              },
              {
               NAME => 'M. Amsi',
               POSITION => 'SENIOR ANIMAL HEALTH OFFICER',
               GRADE => 'P5'
              },
              {
               NAME => 'E. Xenu',
               POSITION => 'SENIOR OFFICER',
               GRADE => 'P5'
              },
            ],
    GAGD => [
             {
              NAME => 'P. Cheru',
              POSITION => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
              GRADE => 'P4'
             },
             {
              NAME => 'B. Burns',
              POSITION => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
              GRADE => 'P4'
             },
             {
              NAME => 'R. Mung',
              POSITION => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
              GRADE => 'P4'
             },
             {
              NAME => 'B. Scherf',
              POSITION => 'ANIMAL PRODUCTION OFFICER',
              GRADE => 'P4'
             },
             {
              NAME => 'I. Hoffmann',
              POSITION => 'CHIEF',
              GRADE => 'P5'
             },
            ]);

for my $division (keys %grades) {
    say "**$division**";
    my %group;
    for my $person (@{ $grades{$division} }) {
        my $position = join ' ', @{ $person }{qw{GRADE POSITION}};
        push @{ $group{$position} }, $person->{NAME};
    }

    for my $position (keys %group) {
        say join ' ', scalar @{ $group{$position} },
                      $position,
                      $group{$position}[0];
        my @remaining_names = @{ $group{$position} };
        shift @remaining_names;
        say "\t$_" for @remaining_names;
    }
    say q();
}
```

#### Update

If you store more information than a name for a person in an array ref (`push push @{ $group{$position} }, [ ... ];`), you can then retrieve it by dereferencing each reference, for example in `map`:

```
    say join ' ', scalar @{ $group{$position} },
                  $position,
                  join "\n\t", map "@$_", @{ $group{$position} };
```

Comment: The count can come from the number of names in `$count{$position}{names}`

Comment: `@remaining_names` isn't really necessary either... (I'm slowly turning your code into mine...)

Comment: I do not know how to thank you for this. One last thing, how would I call and print out other fields such as COUNTRY, AGE, etc. from the data structure { NAME => 'I GREEN', POSITION => 'CHIEF', GRADE => 'P5',COUNTRY=>'US',AGE=>'45', }? I really need to output more than just name, grade and position. –

Comment: @PerlGui: `push` everything you need to get printed, then print it.

Comment: @Choroba,if I push the data as you suggest (i.e.push @{ $group{$position} }, $person->{NAME},$person->{COUNTRY},$person->{DATE_OF_BIRTH},$person->{AGE},$person->{FEMALE},$person->{VACANT};), the counters no longer work as expected.  D1 CHIEF  
 T. Roth
 UNITED STATES OF AMERICA
 12/11/1937
 56
 
 
21 P5 SENIOR OFFICER  
 K. Logh
 UK
 7/27/1957
 57
 * WHAT I AM DOING WRONG?

Comment: @PerlGui: You have to push everything as one, i.e. use an array reference or a hash reference.

Comment: @Choroba, I have done as suggested and am able to  print the hash elements (i.e.push @{ $group{$position} },$rec=[$person->{PWD},$person->{NAME},$person->{COUNTRY},$person->{DATE_OF_BIRTH},$person->{AGE},$person->{FEMALE},$person->{VACANT}]).  The only thing that does work is to print out the hash elements next to the count, grade , position (i.e. say join ' ', scalar @{ $group{$position} },
                      $position,
                      $group{$position}[0];). I always get1 D1 CHIEF ARRAY(0x68dadd8). How do I access the array? You have been help. Thanks again.

Comment: @PerlGui: Just dereference the array reference.

Comment: @Choroba, I can't figure out how to deference the array.I have tried ${$position}[0];  ${$group{$position}}{"AGE"}  still get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Choroba, How do I access the individuals elements @$_ as each person's record comes out in one line. I am not that familiar with map. I really appreciate your time and sorry.

Comment: @PerlGui: Try reading the documentation: [map](http://p3rl.org/map), [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut).

Comment: Thanks a million for all of your great.

Comment: @Choroba. This did it for me:     say join ' ', scalar @{ $group{$position} },
                  $position,
                  join "\n", map "\t$$_[0],$$_[1],$$_[2],$$_[3],$$_[4],$$_[5],$$_[6]", @{ $group{$position} }; I read map and perlreftut. It helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with the code that you've got. Assuming that the hash you've printed out is called `%grades`, I would do the following:

```
foreach my $g (sort keys %$grades) {
    print "**$g**\n";
    # put the info to be printed in a temporary hash
    my %temp;
    foreach (@{$grades->{$g}}) {
        push @{$temp{ $_->{GRADE}." ".$_->{POSITION} }}, $_->{NAME};
    }
    foreach (sort keys %temp) {
        # print a count of the number of names, then the grade/position info
        print scalar @{$temp{$_}} . " $_ "
        # @{$temp{$_}} holds the names, so just sort them and print them out.
        . join("\n\t\t\t", sort @{$temp{$_}}) . "\n";
    }
}
```